# Spivak Problem 19(a) Pre-calculus brush up

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I believe there is a typo in Spivak's answer book. But, my question relates to the statement

> $\left[ \frac{2(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})} \right ]^{2} - \frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}} < 0$

> which yields the Schwarz inequality.

Note: The top right expression should be, I believe, as shown, not as in the answer book ie $(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})$ not $(x_{1}^{2} + y_{1}^{2})$

My question (see below) regards taking the square root in the third line.

For completeness, my attempt.

$$\left[ \frac{2(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})} \right ]^{2} - \frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}} < 0$$

$$\left[ \frac{2(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})} \right ]^{2}  <  \frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}$$

$$ \frac{2(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})}  <  \sqrt{\frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}} = \sqrt{4} \sqrt{\frac{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}} = 2 {\frac{ \sqrt {x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}}{\sqrt {y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}}} = 2 {\frac{ \sqrt {x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}}}{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}  y_{2})\cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{-1} <  \sqrt {x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}  y_{2})\cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{-1}\cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{1} <  \sqrt {x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^{1} $$
$$x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}  y_{2} <  \sqrt {x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \sqrt {y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}} $$

**Question**.

What allows me to assume only the positive square root (in line three).

Comment: Well given $a^2<b^2$, you could conclude $-|b|<-|a|\leqslant \pm a \leqslant |a|< |b|$, obviously taking the positive square roots gives the tighter statement. Any of those is valid though.

Comment: @Macavity Thank you for that. I see and think I understand what you are saying, and clearly it is applicable to my issue, but can't quite see exactly where it applies. Could you elucidate a little further, if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid square roots whenever possible.

In this case,
it is just plain algebra.

$\begin{array}\\
\left[ \frac{2(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})} \right ]^{2} - \frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}
&=\frac{4(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2})^2 }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^2} - \frac{4(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}}\\
&=4\left(\frac{(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2})^2-(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^2}\right)\\
&=4\left(\frac{x_1^2y_1^2+2x_1y_1x_2y_2+x_2^2y_2^2-(x_{1}^{2}y_{1}^{2}+x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} +x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}y_{2}^{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^2}\right)\\
&=4\left(\frac{2x_1y_1x_2y_2-(x_{1}^{2}y_{2}^{2} +x_{2}^{2}y_{1}^{2}) }{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^2}\right)\\
&=4\left(\frac{-(x_1y_2-x_2y_1)^2}{(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})^2}\right)\\
&\lt 0\\
\end{array}
$

unless
$x_1y_2=x_2y_1$
when the two expressions
are equal.

Note that this is just
$(x_{1}y_{1} +x_{2}y_{2})^2
\le(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})(y_{1}^{2} + y_{2}^{2})
$
which shoul;d be familiar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and your answer.. For those of us doing it outside of courses, brushing up on algebra is quite a big deal, so your showing this in full is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are very welcome.